# Installing Chart::Plotly on Strawberry Perl 5.28

Tags: perl, plotly

I am trying to install  Chart::Plotly ( https://metacpan.org/pod/Chart::Plotly) using Strawberry Perl 5.28 and get the below error

```
Created MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Creating new 'Build' script for 'Chart-Plotly' version '0.039'
  PABLROD/Chart-Plotly-0.039.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Build.PL -- OK
Running Build for P/PA/PABLROD/Chart-Plotly-0.039.tar.gz
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----     PABLROD/Chart-Plotly-0.039.tar.gz    ----
    Devel::IPerl [requires,optional]
    PDL [build_requires]
    Params::Validate [requires]
    Ref::Util [requires]
    UUID::Tiny [requires]
Running install for module 'PDL'
Checksum for C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\sources\authors\id\E\ET\ETJ\PDL-2.021.tar.gz ok
Couldn't move C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\tmp-20036\PDL-2.021\Graphics to C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\PDL-2.021-0\Graphics: No such file or directory; #82295? CPAN::VERSION=2.20; File::Copy::VERSION=2.33; C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\tmp-20036\PDL-2.021\Graphics exists; C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\PDL-2.021-0\Graphics does not exist; cwd=C:/STRAWB~1/cpan/build/tmp-20036;
```

Any Idea how to fix it?

Comment: It installs fine here on Windows 10, Strawberry Perl 5.30.1. How did you try to install the module (which command did you use) ?

Comment: I used >cpan then install Chart::Plotly (also tried notest and force install )but get the same results